# Copy data of each table from server A to server B dynamically using SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

My task is to create workflow in SSIS where it will be copying data of each table from server A to the same tables in server B. For now, I have stopped in step where I'm taking data from A server and copy it to server B. Till now I have created workflow where steps are as below:

1. Read data from Excel file where there are placed names of tables to be processed
2. Insert this rows in destination database (server B) for future
3. In Control Flow connected above steps to next object - Execute SQL task where inside I'm taking all loaded names from table to global project variable named as "GlobalListOfTables".
4. Created another variable "localTable" where I'm storing each row of "GlobalListOfTables" variable/set which I'm using it later in "FOR LOOP".

Here I have stopped and what I want to do is:

5. Inside this LOOP get all data from source server of each table using created "localTable" variable and after insert this all data into destination server into the same table name as is in "localTable" variable.

This last point 5 makes me a little bit confused because tables are gonna be different from each other so there is no one pattern of tables struckture.

Can someone let me know how should I do in SSIS and which control should I take from available list to achieve point 5?

Comment: Sounds to me like SSIS may be the wrong tool for the job. Have you looked into replication?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/transfer-sql-server-objects-task?view=sql-server-2017?

Comment: Do you need to copy database object? Is that Correct?

Comment: Is this a classroom assignment or a workplace assignment? I ask because in the workplace, relying on an Excel sheet instead of the system tables would be a bad idea, and using SSIS for this task would also be a bad idea, so that will take you in one direction. If this is a classroom assignment, then those are the rules you're stuck with and we can focus on making the wrong tools for the job do what you need them to do.

Comment: Best approach will be to restore DB from Server A to B. You can write a Simple sql query in the Ssis package to do this .Then you can schedule the package to run and wallaa you have the data in the table at your destination server DB, but the schema and DB are the same . If u are trying to insert into a completely new DB with different table scheme best of luck with that . You need to give us details like tables scheme columns all these things. You can also link the server and use sql query to insert and schedule it as a sql job

Comment: Does the list of tables change? Do you need to do updates (and track time changes) or simply refresh the entire table? Because if both of these answers are no, you can do a simple Execute SQL task to Truncate the table, then a data flow to insert again. Repeat these 2 tasks for each table. If you need to do the tables dynamically or need to do updates then this becomes much more complex.

Comment: @user3920526 i don't think that this is the best approach, have you `Transfer database Task` and `Transfer SQL Server Objects Task` in SSIS?

Comment: I cannot restore database or copy from one server to another. It is task from my work not classroom. Tables provided in Excel file can change so it has to be dynamic refreshmt. Tables on both databases are the same if it comes to structure. The only difference is that they are on two separate servers. What I need to do is take all data from table A on server A and place it in server B into table B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use C# SMO objects from a Script Task to do the transfer for a dynamic table list.  The SSIS loop won't be necessary.  The SSIS object variable (`GlobalListOfTables`) will need to be included in the `ReadOnlyVariables` field on the Script Task.  Make sure to add Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended and Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo references to the Script Task in addition to those listed below.

```
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.OleDb;



       string databaseName = "DatabaseName";
       List<string> tableNames = new List<string>();
       DataTable dt = new DataTable();
       OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();

        //get table names from SSIS object variable
       dataAdapter.Fill(dt, Dts.Variables["User::SourceServerName"].Value);

        //populate list
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
          tableNames.Add(dr[0].ToString());
        }

        //create source server object
        Server srcServ = new Server(@"SourceServerName");
        srcServ.ConnectionContext.LoginSecure = true;
        srcServ.ConnectionContext.StatementTimeout = 600;
        srcServ.ConnectionContext.Connect();

        //define source database as smo object
        Database sourceDatabase = srcServ.Databases["SourceDatabaseName"];

        Transfer transfer = new Transfer();
        transfer.Database = sourceDatabase;

        //set destination server and database
        transfer.DestinationServer = @"DestinationServerName";
        transfer.DestinationDatabase = databaseName;

        //overwrite objects if they exist
        transfer.DropDestinationObjectsFirst = true;

        transfer.CopyAllObjects = false;
        transfer.CopySchema = true;

        //include data
        transfer.CopyData = true;

        foreach (Table t in sourceDatabase.Tables)
        {   
            //extract table names that were originally in SSIS object variable and avoid system objects
            if (tableNames.Contains(t.Name) && !t.IsSystemObject)
            {
                transfer.ObjectList.Add(t);
            }
        }
        //transfer objects
         transfer.TransferData();
```

Comment: This code looks really good and is very promising. I need to check that and let you know @userfl89 if it will work in my case. Thank  you for this code.

Comment: I have taken your script and put it inside my workflow. Seems to be working generally but I encountered one problem. When I run this workflow this script is entered by process and running forever without ending transfer. Table for testing is not so big - 1000 rows only. I joined script which displays "Job Done" if transfer is completed but it isn't. Do you know what is the problem here?

Comment: Script is working but it is not transfering data to destination tables. Tables are empty after that

Comment: Did you set the CopyData property of the Transfer object to true (right above the foreach loop)?  And it's running for long periods of time with a single table?  Running this with several tables of a similar size didn't take very long, around 10 roughly seconds, when I tested it.  Is there any resource contention on the server?  Also, is it connecting correctly to both servers?  I ran into a similar issue with the timing, but once the server connections were correctly created (i.e. ConnectionContext, DestinationServer  settings) this resolved it.

Comment: I have updated line where to each table I added "dbo." string before each table and it accelerated a lot. This part is solved. According to DATA I set this object to TRUE but data of each table is still not copied. Script runs sucessfully but there is no data in destination tables. Connection is set up now correctly.

Comment: I didn't have any issues transferring the data before, but to confirm I just copied/pasted the code I posted above and all rows were transferred, including one table that's significantly larger than the one you're testing. You've probably already checked this, but does the source table have data at the time of transfer, and is the order that the properties are set/methods called in your code the same as what I submitted?

Comment: Everything is working perfectly. I checked again and someone was/is touching data that I need to transfer. It is solved. Checked now again and data for tables is transfered without a problem. Thank you for your time and solution for this. Marked as solution.

Comment: For others: It is also very important to se correct "Time out" for this task.

Answer (score 3):

## Transfer Database Task and Transfer SQL Server Objects Task

If you are looking to copy all data from a database to another you should refer to the `Transfer Database Task` and `Transfer SQL Server Objects Task`:

Based on the [Transfer Database Task official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/transfer-database-task?view=sql-server-2017):

> The Transfer Database task transfers a SQL Server database between two instances of SQL Server. In contrast to the other tasks that only transfer SQL Server objects by copying them, the Transfer Database task can either copy or move a database. This task can also be used to copy a database within the same server.

Also, based on [Transfer SQL Server Objects Task official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/transfer-sql-server-objects-task?view=sql-server-2017):

> The Transfer SQL Server Objects task transfers one or more types of objects in a SQL Server database between instances of SQL Server. For example, the task can copy tables and stored procedures. Depending on the version of SQL Server that is used as a source, different types of objects are available to copy. For example, only a SQL Server database includes schemas and user-defined aggregates.

## Detailed articles

There are many article describing how to work with these tasks and all available options, as example:

- [Transfer Database Task and Transfer SQL Server Objects Task in SSIS](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2064/transfer-database-task-and-transfer-sql-server-objects-task-in-ssis/)
- [Copy all objects from one database to another in SSIS using “Transfer SQL Server Objects Task”](https://awesomesql.wordpress.com/2009/08/18/copy-all-objects-from-one-database-to-another-in-ssis-using-transfer-sql-server-objects-task/)

Comment: You are right here but I need to do this dynamically with list of tables. Solution that is working for me is above but thank's for that also.