# Copy Table to Table From Different Servers

Tags: c#, ssis

We have a database with over 1000 tables.  There is a copy of this database on Server A and Server B.  We need to create two connections (one for Server A and one for Server B) and copy each table in Server A to Server B.

We have done this with a SQL Link Server but the performance is painfully slow.  SSIS is really fast but we have to map each field unless we use the import/export wizard.  Therefore, we would like to do this in C# and stick the script into a SCRIPT Task control in SSIS.

Two things we need are:

1. Avoid mapping fields since there are over 1k tables.  The tables are
   exactly the same between the two databases.
2. Ability to USE a WHERE clause on the source

**We would like to do it similar to:**

```
INSERT INTO SERVER_B.Database.dbo.TABLE_N T2
SELECT * FROM SERVER_A.Database.dbo.TABLE_N T1
WHERE T1.ModifiedDate > '01-01-2019'
```

I have not touched C# for a while so please be detail.  Or if you have a tutorial link, that will be great.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you back up the database in Server A and then restore it Server B?

Comment: We do have a process that does that to sync it on a daily basis.  It takes about 45-60 minutes with a SSIS package.  I am trying to do a data refresh which should take less than 5 minutes for all tables.  Also, Server A belongs to the vendor so there are some limitations.

Comment: I think this is one way of doing it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54831745/copy-data-of-each-table-from-server-a-to-server-b-dynamically-using-ssis